# Macro recorder or programmed macros, a button expedition

Tags: scripting, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am not proficient in either macro scripting in excel or scripting in general. I have a general sense of syntax and language formatting so I'm not necessarily going in empty handed with trying to program my owns scripts and I'm leaning this way due to the unique scenario I will be using the spreadsheet.

Essentially I'm wanting to track some data pertaining to slots for a pet project.  What I desire is a "start" button that prompts which column I would like my "session" to start in, moves the selected cell to that column and prompts for a starting balance and fills it into the appropriate column; then there are a choice of buttons from which one that pertains to each of my bet options (there are 4) and that will fill in a column net to my balance with the appropriate amount as well as update the balance column to the next row. Lastly I would like to have 6(button) options for certain indicators I would like to track.

All of this I would like to run off of keyboard hotkeys if possible. Ultimately I'm mainly asking for resources since most of the "tutorials" show how to make a button, and some sense of hello world macros, but I'm mainly needing to find page navigation macros, input, take existing data, and append or modify that data with current variables.

-Thank You for any advice or resources and for your guys' time :D

I'm currently trying macro recording but it seems a little but specific to copy pasta situations and not so much the calculation, though small, but redundant that I could optimize with better scripting. I'm also finding that most of the buttons output to a text document outside of libre calc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Have you looked at [Andrew's macro document](https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php)? It's better to start there rather than trying to use recorder dispatcher code. Beyond that, the question needs to be focused on one issue. Requests for code writing are generally not accepted here.

Comment: This is a great resouce, this is exactly the type of resource I was looking for. :D